# convert _id to string in mongodb

Tags: node.js, arrays

I have a mongodb query in my node js project like this

```
async function getRoomByCount(client, roomCount) {
  rooms = await client.db(database).collection(roomCollection)
    .findOne({ count: { $lt: roomCount } });    
  return rooms;   
}
```

This works well and returns one item from db, but the _id is not readable. Output is like this

```
{_id: ObjectID, name: 'China_amber_llama', count: 3, timestamp: Sat Aug 15 2020 02:48:18 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)}
```

_id field here is an object, how can i convert it to a string. I am expecting like this "5f3706a2112c7c2b9cc0fc81" but unable to do it using nodejs. any help
I tried `rooms._id.id, JSON.stringify(rooms._id.id.toJSON)` all these kind of combinations are not working.

I have this in my database

```
_id:5f3706a2112c7c2b9cc0fc81
name:China_amber_llama
count:3
timestamp:2020-08-14T21:48:18.733+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `toString()` function on the `_id` field to convert it to a string.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/